# Custom categorical threshold axis break on a continuous scale in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, threshold, continuous

Considering the following plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cyl))) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Weight", breaks = c(2, 3, 4, 5))
```

Does anyone know of a way to replace the value of e.g. 5 with a categorical break such as "Above 5", with the three observations appearing on this created break line? I am looking for a way to include outliers in a plot without skewing it yet still be able to show information pertaining to them (in this case, their mpg values) instead of excluding them completely.

The following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cyl))) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Weight", breaks = c(2, 3, 4, >5), labels = c(2, 3, 4, "Above 5")))
```

Does not work due to the ">" symbol in breaks. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: How would the ggplot know the desired location on the axis without a specific numerical value?
Why not keep the breaks=c(2,3,4,5) with the new labels?

Comment: In this case yes of course, but what if the weights for the points above 5 were in the thousands? The plot would not make sense visually anymore and then it would be better in my opinion to have a threshold value e.g. above 5 or 1000, etc.

Comment: @ykl it does not work because your passing a categorical value to a continuous function, `scale_y_continuous`. Replace the `scale_y_continuous` with `scale_y_discrete(name="Weight", breaks=c(">5"))`. However, I'm unsure if this suggestion is logical or not because the `wt` in the `mtcars` data is not discrete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that a simple data manipulation procedure prior to plotting gives what I want.

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars <- mtcars %>%  mutate(wt2 = case_when(wt < 5  ~ wt,
                              wt > 5 ~ 5))
```

The above code will assign the value of 5 to any mpg value above 5, so that these appear on the same break line. Then I can plot, and the overlap in points can be shown with change in alpha value.

```
  library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt2)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cyl), alpha = 0.2, size = 2)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Weight", breaks = c(2, 3, 4, 5), labels = c(2, 3, 4, "Above 5"))
```

Thank you for your comments.